# Adding page numbers to footnotes using style=verbose-ibid style

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, multiple-citations

I've just started using LaTeX and would be really grateful for some help in with citations.

I have been using the verbose-ibid style and understand how to add page numbers when referring to a single item in a footnote, I'm struggling, however, to include pages numbers when citing more than one one item in the same footnote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, backend=biber, giveninits=true, citepages=omit]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
ipsum\autocite[200]{spiegelberg}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The code above allows me to generate two footnotes, which each include page numbers. Please could someone tell me how to combine these citations into one footnote, while retaining the page numbers.

Comment: How would you now which page belongs to `Lorem` and which to `ipsum`? Can you explain the desired output with a mockup?

Comment: Do you want `lorem\autocites[381]{sigfridsson}[380]{spiegelberg}`?

Comment: Great, many thanks. I wasn't aware of the "\autocites" function, which has done the trick.