# Editing a citation style (verbose-ibid), removing certain information

Tags: biblatex

I have been using the `verbose-ibid` style and wondered if someone could let me know how to **exclude** ISBN numbers, language and publisher from  footnotes, short of updating the corresponding `biblatex` file?

Comment: You can make it much easier for people to answer your question if you include a fully working example document that shows what you have so far. Do you also want to exclude the data from the bibliography at the end?

Comment: re: the Bibliography, I'd not thought that far ahead, but yes, that would be ideal! Re: working example, I'm afraid I'm using a large biblatex file, which was created from my Zotero references, which makes it difficult to upload an example. I have tried to remove the information that I don't want to appear in the footnotes from the biblatex file and the corresponding Zotero entry, but this doesn't seem to have done the trick.

Comment: It would be enough to just show one example entry from the `.bib` file. But we definitely need to see what else is going on. I can work from your very good MWE from your other question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/500752/35864), but it would be a shame if I found a solution and then you told me it is incompatible with what you are doing because there is more going on in your document with `biblatex` than that example shows.

Answer (score 1):

For the `isbn` there is the global option `isbn=false` that you could use to suppress the output, but a similar option does not exist for most fields (e.g. `publisher`).

If you want the fields gone in the citations *and* the bibliography, the simplest option is to clear them out with a Biber sourcemap. That way they won't even reach `biblatex`. (See also [Disable ISSN but keep ISBN with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40097/35864), [Excessive fields in biblatex could not be removed if using \fullcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229428/35864), [Remove title in biblatex references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141822/35864), [Problems in suppressing "series" field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128928/35864) for more on suppressing fields.)

```
\documentclass[dutch]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=isbn, null]
      \step[fieldset=language, null]
      \step[fieldset=publisher, null]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
  language     = {english},
  isbn         = {978-0691020358},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Lorem\autocite{nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Nussbaum, Martha. Aristotle’s „De Motu Animalium”. Princeton, 1978.]

Note that the document language is set to a language other than `english`, because otherwise the `clearlang` option would automatically suppress the `language = {english},`.